# Нужно сделать так чтобы код от сейфа можно было изменить только в том случае, если сейф уже открыт

Tags: java

Нужно сделать так чтобы код от сейфа можно было изменить только в том случае, если сейф уже открыт. Если сейф закрыт, но я пытаюсь изменить его код, то должна выходить ошибка. Ошибку пусть выдает через sout. То есть хотелось бы без булена решить

```
public class Safe {
    int pin = 1234;

    void start() {
        change(4321);
        open(1234);
    }

    void close() {
        System.out.println("Safe close");
    }

    void open(int code) {

        if (code == pin) {
            System.out.println("Welcome");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }

    }

    void change(int a) {
            pin = a;
            
    }

}
```

Comment: добавьте булевую переменную, которая хранит текущий статус. в open/close обновляйте.

Comment: а если без boolen решить? Ну то есть ошибку пусть через sout выдает

Comment: можно int использовать, но мне кажется, это не совсем верно будет

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее объяснить пж. Где создать int и что вообще с ней делать. Так логику понимаю, то есть если не выполнен open, то change выполнять тоже не должен - должна выскакивать ошибка. Значит должно быть условие if. Просто как все это дело реализовать, здесь сложности появляются

Comment: @Kamran, если вы хотите решить без `boolean`, то можете конечно с помощью `int` решить (указывать 0 когда закрыт и 1 когда открыт, к примеру). Но использование `boolean` более интуитивно понятный способ

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Safe {
  int pin = 1234;
  boolean isOpen = false;

  void start() {
    change(4321);
    open(1234);
  }

  void close() {
    System.out.println("Safe close");
    isOpen = false;
  }

  void open(int code) {
    if (code == pin) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        isOpen = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
  }

  void change(int a) {
    if (isOpen) {
      pin = a;
    } else {
      System.out.println("It is close");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно хранить состояние о том открыт сейф или нет, когда вы пытаетесь изменить код.
Самое верное решение, как вам уже подсказали, использовать boolean.

```
void change(int a) {
   if (isOpen) {
     pin = a;
   } else {
     // сообщение
   }
}
```

А там уже ошибку давать через `sout` или как хотите